# Android CDC communication in micro USB host to read from device

Tags: android, serial-communication, usbserial, cdc, usb-hostcontroller

I'm trying to implement CDC communication between IMX board and android tab. I have seen couple of tutorials and libraries but all are done through OTG cables. I need to implement the communication by connecting USB on IMX and connecting micro USB directly to android tab(without OTG cable). Past few days I struck on this. I tried the sample code of USB Host api from developer.android.com but its not detecting my device.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to implement above functionality. Initially i was trying with USB Host Api, which will make android as Host and provide power to the connected device, hence we have to Use OTG cable. For my requirement have to use USB Accessory API which will make the device which is connect to android as host. Also we can connect the android device directly with micro usb connector. For more details refer  [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb)